# Spaces of functions which remain linear combination of themselves after being convolved by gaussian?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, soft-question, convolution, smooth-functions

Say we have the following set of functions

$$\mathcal S = \{f_1,f_2,\cdots\}$$

so that for any $n$ there exist uniquely a set of $ \{ c_k \}$:

$$(f_n * g)(t) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^+} c_k f_k(t)$$

(or maybe normalized, but that is not of importance here)

, where $g(t)$ is a gaussian function:
$$g(t) = \exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

How can I find such sets $\mathcal S$ ?

Can I for example prove or disprove whether the set of monomials $f_k(t) = t^k$ is such a space?

Comment: This is certainly true if $(f_k)_k$ is an arbitrary orthonormal basis of $L^2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I thought so too. But what if it is an orthonormal basis of some subspace of $L^2$